# Swift check if version is 1.2 or 2.0

Tags: ios, swift

I wonder if there is a way to check what version of swift something is using?

I see a lot of github repos but many of them don't say what version of swift they are using

Comment: Nope, that is not a duplicate!

Comment: Can you give an example of one git repo where you are unsure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Man, no have way to know if you don't read the code.

I have a link can help you identify some new in Swift 2, maybe it help you check if is Swift 1.2 or Swift 2.0

Example, if you see this

```
do {
    try doStuff()
    print("Success")
} catch {
    print("An error occurred.")
}
```

or

```
guard username.text.characters.count > 0 else {
    return
}
```

it is some new in Swift 2.

I don't know other way to know, only reading code.

[What's new in Swift 2](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/swift2)

Comment: I agree: you have to look for code that is not swift 1.2 conform to know that what you are looking at is actually swift 2.

Comment: The swift 1.2 style code is compatible with swift 2.0 but, some details had modify and because this maybe cause some errors, like `confg(#var1, var2 value2, var3 value3)` but it in Swift 2.0 is `config(var1 value1, var2 value2, var3 value3)`, but if you look in the line in Xcode, you can click and Xcode fix for you that's simples issue. Don't be afraid when use code Swif 1.2, XCode can fix for you, or you post here someone help you with problem fast.